# filter out an array of items from another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On load, I'm receiving a list of image URL's that I want to hide from the users view.

I have an array of all the original image URL's as well.

I want to create a new array with out the hidden images URL's.

I am using the `array.filter()` function but It not removing the URL's from the array.

I think its the way I am loading the functions because hidden images is initially null, than it loads again and it has its values in there, but im not really sure what im not doing to get this to work properly.

Thanks for any insights.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function getImage(jobID) {
    const imageURL = await Storage.list(`${jobID}/completed/`);
    let imagesAsArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < imagesToDownload.length; i++) {
      const imagesDownloaded = await getURLFromS3(imagesToDownload[i]);
      imagesAsArray.push(imagesDownloaded)
    }
    return imagesAsArray
  }

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      const downloadedImage = await getImage(job);
      if (hiddenImages !== null) {
        hide(downloadedImage)
      } else {
        setImages(downloadedImage);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }
  onLoad();
}, [job]);

function hide(imagesToFilter) {
  const ImagesToView = (imagesToFilter).filter(image =>(!image.includes(hiddenImages)));
  console.log(ImagesToView)
  setImages(ImagesToView);
}
```

`hiddenImages` Value Example:

[image]

`console.log(ImagesToView)`

[image]

Comment: Aren't you interested in whether `hiddenImages` contains `image`, not the other way around? `image` isn't an array. Why is `hide` async, and why are you awaiting it?

Comment: I want to return a list of images that I want to display, not hide. I want to remove the URLS stored in the ```hiddenImages``` value from the ```imagesToFilter``` value.

Comment: as for the Async, that's just me being sloppy on my part. Im a self taught newbie, only 6 months in. I haven't gotten to cleaning that up before I posted my question. I was originally returning the ```ImagesToView``` from the ```hide()``` function and then calling ```SetImage()``` with what was returned from the function.

Comment: You probably just need to flip it around and look for a specific image in the list of hidden images: `!hiddenImages.includes(image)`